# Ms access export to excel

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

everyone,
I have few queries in ms access 2010 that has 2 parameters - month and year.
What I need is to export results of this queries to separate files, but the values of the parameters will be the same.
So I would like user to enter this 2 parameters one time and the macro to do the rest.
How is that possible?
I know how to export to excel using ExportWithFormatting. Also I know how to set local or temp variable, but how do I pass them to ExportWithFormatting then?
Please help with your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three different methods of passing the values to queries.

1. You can put controls on a form, and have the queries reference the values in the controls on the form.
2. You can create global variables to contain the parameters, create functions that return the value of the parameters that you can use in the query.  Have the user enter the values either in controls on a form, or using the InputBox() function.
3. If your not using forms, you can put the values in a local table and reference them using DLookup() or DFirst() functions.

Comment: Thank you!
Eventually I created a table and used a form that I open before exporting data, to change my parameters.